# Gtest per test tear down after fixture destructor

Tags: c++, googletest

I know that Gtest has a `TearDown`, but it is called before the destructor of the fixture class is called. I also know that there is the `TearDownTestCase`, which is called after all the tests using that fixture are executed and after the last instance of the fixture is deleted.

Are there any form of tear down that executes for each test but after the destructor of the fixture has been called?

Trying to explain the problem I want to solve with this approach. This is what the code looks like:

```
class c;

class MyFixture : public ::testing::Test, public A {
...
static C *c;

    SetUp(){
        c = new C();
        SetC(c) // this function is from base class A
    }
};

TEST_F(B, test1){
...
}
```

I don't have access to the implementation of A. What happens is that I always need to create and destroy `c` on each test, but if I destroy it before the destructor of base class A is called, something happens there that causes the test to exit (without any explicit error, it just exits with code 255).

The real solution is probably some fix on `class A`'s destructor. But while I don't have it, I was wondering if there was a standard way to destroy `c` after each test, after the destructor of A is called.

Comment: Looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the problem to which you think this is the solution.

Comment: @MikeKinghan You might be right, I edit the question to explain what I want to solve.

Comment: This isn't how to write a gtest fixture class. You should derive it from [::testing::Test](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/Primer.md#test-fixtures-using-the-same-data-configuration-for-multiple-tests)

Comment: @MikeKinghan My mistake, forgot to put it on the example code. Included it in the question now.

Comment: So why is `C *c` static? If it was just a data member of `MyFixture` then @OlegBogdanov's answer would apply? And you say that you create/destroy a new C one-for-one with MyFixture construction/destruction.

Comment: @MikeKinghan It wouldn't work. The destructor of A, for some reason, "crashes" if `c` was destroyed before, and since A is the base class, it will always be the last to be destroyed.